# MS SQL Server and MS Access returning different results for same formula

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm in the process of converting an Access query to a SQL Server view.

When I perform a specific calculation in SQL Server, I'm getting different results than in MS Access. I've validated that the input data-set for both are identical.

I suspect the issue is related to the fact the input values in SQL are Float while Access uses a Number datatype. Since I'm not real clear on the characteristics of the Number datatype, I am not sure how to adjust my SQL values to get the same results. (And the results of the two must mach for the project to proceed.) I've created a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed1f8/10/0) with some example data and the formula in question. I used the identical query in Access to verify that there is a difference. Thanks for your help!

Here are the results I'm getting:

```
id  Emisn (SQL)     Emisn (Access)
1   0.0000329819    0.0000439814
2   0.0113590774    0.0116101130
3   0.2316721011    0.2397806246
4   0.0001388906    0.0001852106
5   0.0046684742    0.0048496693
6   0.0042396525    0.0043333488
7   0.7346706060    0.7603840772
8   6.2285552134    6.2306588976
9   0.0058069245    0.0060101669
```

Comment: you've told us what the query is, but you haven't told us what the respective results are in the 2 different RDBMS are, nor what you want the result to be.

Comment: At a quick glance, this might have to do with precision.  Try with changing the hardcoded integers in your Emisn calculation to floats.  I.e.  `1000` to `1000.0` and `1` to `1.0`

Comment: `float` *guarantees* you'll get rounding errors. If you want repeatable results *don't* use `float`. Use a type with specific precision, eg `numeric(p,s)`

Comment: @LukStorms I can't believe it was that simple. There's only one hard-coded integer in the formula and that was the division by 1000. When I changed it to 1000.0, the results match!! How do I give you credit for answering the question?

Comment: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos. Unfortunately in this case, I inherited the database as is. If I create any new tables, I'll definitely do that.

Comment: Then you'll have to live with the differences. At least check the sizes of the types you use in Access and SQL Server to see whether they are different. `float` by default is [8 bytes on SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql), although the size changes if you specify a precision. Access has Single (4 bytes) and Double (8 bytes) types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, to get the same result in MS SQL Server as in Access it was as easy as changing the hardcoded int `1000` to a float `1000.0`.

The reason for that is also simple.
In MS SQL Server, when you divide an INT by an INT you get an INT.

But if you divide an INT by a FLOAT then you get a FLOAT.

For example this simple snippet shows it:

```
declare @v_int int = 2667;
select @v_int as v_int, @v_int / 1000 as int_divided_by_int, @v_int / 1000.0 as int_divided_by_float;
```

Returns:

```
v_int int_divided_by_int int_divided_by_float
----- ------------------ --------------------
2667  2                  2.667000
```

Of course, because of this loss in precision with the INT, this would give a different result for the `[Emisn]` calculation.